# Derivative of $-\csc(2x)$

Tags: derivatives

Is the following reasoning correct?
$$-\csc2x = -1[\csc(2x)\cdot\cot(2x)] = -1[\csc(2x)\cdot\cot(2x)\cdot2\cdot2]$$

I am unsure whether that is correct so far because I do not know if the derivatives of the $\csc$ and $\cot$ need to be taken again due to the chain rule

Comment: Do you mean $-\csc^2(x)$ or $-\csc(2x)$? As it stands, this is very ambiguous.

Comment: I mean the second one

Comment: @AlexR: If you look in the edit history, the “edit approved” link above the editor name shows who approved the edit (in this case, the OP).

Comment: @Hello You may want to take a look at [this help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for a few tips on MathJax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}(-\csc (2x))= -\frac{d}{dx}(\csc (2x)) = -\big(-\csc(2x)\cot(2x)\big)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(2x)$$

$$ = 2\csc (2x)\cot(2x)$$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the $\csc(x) = -\cot(x)\cdot\csc(x)$
The answer to your question is $2\cot(2x)\csc(2x)$
Simply, you have to use the chain rule.
First of all take the derivative of $\csc$ , then the $2x$ and multiply them.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to take the derivative again of the 2x due to the chain rule?

Comment: You only take the derivative of $2x$ once, since that's the inner function of $-\csc(2x)$.

Comment: @Hello No, you take the derivative of $2x$ which is $2$ and multiply it by the rest.

Comment: @FreeMind You may want to take a look at [this help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for a few tips on MathJax.

Comment: @amWhy I edited my answer before you posting it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use sine and cosine?

The derivative can then be easily calculated using basic differentiation rules:
$$
-\frac{d}{dx}\csc(2x)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{-1}{\sin(2x)}=\frac{1}{\sin^2(2x)}\cdot \cos(2x)\cdot 2=2\cos(2x)\csc(2x)
$$

---

"Is the following reasoning correct?" NO. You miss the derivative symbol, not to say other aspects.